# C#. Вопросы по внедрению DI (dependency injection) в готовый проект

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, di

Есть приложение по N-уровневой модели:

```
    UI
    Business logic
    Domain (абстрактное хранилище)
    DataAcsessLayer1 (например sql хранилище)
    DataAcsessLayer2 (например Nosql хранилище)
    DataAcsessLayer3 (например file XML хранилище)

Много проектов с самостоятельными сервисами (коммуникация, вывод видео, вывод звука). 
У каждого сервиса своя система загрузки настрек из XML.
Эти сервисы использует Business logic.
```

DI  в данном проекте нет, архитектура проекта более менее построена по SOLID принципам. (UI на winForms и WPF есть, вскоре займусь и AspNetCore MVC)
Хотелось бы внедрить DI.
Но в голове у меня не совсем законченная карина как это делать).

ШАГИ:

Выделяем корень компоновки:

Win-Forms: В классе Program создается главная форма (MainForm) приложения.

WPF: В Классе App переопределить метод OnStartup и в нем создать MainViewModel (через DI) и вручную создать окно.
      var viewModel = container.Resolve(); 
      var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
      mainWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
      mainWindow.Show();

1. В корне компановки загружаем ВСЕ настройки приложения (Общие настройки и настройки нужные для создания каждого сервиса).
2. Настраиваем все зависимости DI контейнера (резолвим граф создания всех сервисов), исходя из загруженных настроек.
   ISoundPlayer -> OmneoSoundPlayer
   IUserRepositiry -> SqlUserRepository
   ...
3. Внедряем зависимости в конструктор главной формы.

   MainForm(ISoundPlayer sp, IUserRepositiry usr)
      {
        //Business logic создается напрямую (через new) и использует внедренные зависимости. 
      }

   Запускаем главную форму:
      var mf= Container.Resolve();
      Application.Run(mf);

ВОПРОСЫ:

1. Если внутри MainForm есть еще формы, которые мы открытваем при нажатии на кнопку.
   Например
   MainForm->AdminForm->UsersForm

   И у UsersForm есть зависимость от IUserRepositiry
   UsersForm(IUserRepositiry usRep) 
   {
   }

   Как внедрять IUserRepositiry? Я так понимаю это и есть основной профит, что можно делать так внутри AdminForm, не пробрасывая все зависимости с MainForm:

   var c = new Container();
   var userRep= c.Resolve();
   var f= UsersForm(userRep);
2. Где задавать настройки mapping (Например для AutoMapper) на все слои приложения? (Тоже в корне компоновки?).
   Каждый слой, сервис, рабоатет со своими сущностями, соответсвенно для склеивания нужен маппер
3. Из контейнеров хочу остановится на Autofac. Довольно плотно использовал CastleWindsor в 1 проекте ASP net MVC, Autofac на первый взгляд кажется лаконичнее.
   Вы как думаете? что лутше?
4. Возможность перехвата DI контейнера, для внедрения сквозной функциональности, активно используете?
   Например для внедрения ЛОГОВ и АУДИТА действий пользователя.
   Есть ли подводные камни?
5. В данный момент все сервисы представляют из себя самостоятельную единицу, т.е. при создании сревиса, знают откуда братьс свои настройки (лезут в XML файлы).
   Я так понимаю это противоречит DI.  И в самом начале я должен загрузить нужные настройки для ВСЕГО ВСЕГО и создать правила по созданию сервисов с этими настройками через DI?

//-------------------------------------------------
УТОЧНЕНИЯ:
1. Т.е. все представления регистрируются в DI. Для WPF MVVM (использую Caliburn micro) чтобы отобразить окно надо создать ViewModel и вызвать на ней Show().
Т.е. в обработчике команды от кнопки я должен создать ViewMidel со всеми зависимостями.

```
var c = new Container();
var userVm= c.Resolve<UserViewModel>();
userVM.Show();
```

В WinForms получается все также, только создается сама форма через DI.

2. Если взаимодействие 2-ух сервисов (одному сервису нужны данные от другого преобразованные через маппер):

   var s1= new Service1();
   var s2Entity= Mapper.Map(s1.Entity);
   var s2= new Service2(s2Entity);

Нужно ли такое задавать в корне компоновки?

4. Сейчас также использую декораторы, попробую перехват).
5. Тут согласен, если  сервиса есть зависимости то их описываем в DI, если внутренние настройки, то просто сервис грузит их сам когда ему надо.

ctor Service(ISoundPlayer)
{
   LoadXml();
}

До Caliburn micro использовал Catel, но он очень монструозный и требует наличия Model со своими атрибутами. Prism можно использовать бесплатно? 
И как вы регистрируете разные модули своего приложения в Prism? Вы имели в виду через DI?

Comment: У вас какая-то мешанина из `WinForms` и `WPF`. Вы в одном десктопном приложении используете сразу вместе эти две технологиии? И зачем нужна `WinForms`, если `WPF` перекрывает все возможности первой? Нет никакой необходимости подключать `MainViewModel` в классе `App`, когда это можно спокойно сделать в конструкторе гл.окна приложения.

Comment: первый проект был WinForms . Он в продакшене все еще, в том году перешли на WPF, но пока приходится поддерживать 2 проекта. Скоро Web api писать, это будет 3 проект. Можно не обращать внимание на конкретную UI технологию, нужна общая картина.

Comment: Для `WPF` есть [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140(v=pandp.40).aspx) в нем всё есть в том числе и MEF DI. У `AspNetCore` есть свой встроенный DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Есть разные подходы как показывать дочерние представления. В призме есть регионы, или можно свою фабрику представлений сделать, или ещё как - тут нет конкретных рекомендаций. Основная суть в том, что в итоге дочернее представление, как и основное представление, создается через контейнер.
2. То, что используется всем приложением, лучше задавать в точке входа либо оформлять модулем и регистрировать модуль первым (до всех остальных модулей)
3. Я работал с Castle, Unity - по мне так разницы особо нет.
4. Пользовался для этого декораторами - это больше кода, но код понятней. Пользовался перехватом - тоже сильная вещь.
5. Откуда сервисы берут настройки - это отношения к DI не имеет.

Я обычно в десктопном приложении делю проект на самостоятельные модули, каждый модуль регистрируется независимо от других модулей - то есть каждый модуль содержит какую то полезную функциональность. Чтобы отключить функциональность, достаточно просто не грузить модуль, но приложение вцелом все равно запустится. Собственно, к этому и располагает упомянутый [PRISM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479(v=pandp.40).aspx)

**UPD**

1. PRISM использует регионы для отображения представлений. То есть вы ему говорите, например, "в регионе с таким то именем я хочу видеть этот контрол" - и дальше регион менеджер позаботится о том, чтобы отрисовать контрол и загрузить и орисовать связанные контролы (например, когда контрол, что вы добавляете, содержит дочерние регионы). Выглядит это [как то так](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.MainModule/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L40), пример [дочернего региона](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.MainModule/ServerInfoControl.xaml#L42). Также вы можете переопределить поведение менеджера регионов, написав свой адаптер (мне это требовалось, так как мне надо быдо не просто контрол в конртол засунуть, а показать новое представление в отдельном окне/табе), [пример адаптера](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.MainModule/AvalonDockRegionAdapter.cs). Но я ещё отмечу, что использование регионов в призме (как и других его частей) необязательно - вы вольны открывать новые представления любым способом.
2. Если у вас есть сервис, которому для работы нужен другой сервис, то передавайте его как зависимость. Если серсисы независимы и меняются только данными, то должен быть третий сервис, у которого первые зва сервиса как зависимости.

Comment: Ответил ниже в собственном ответе.

Comment: @Aldmi PRISM бесплатный, лицензия и примеры [тут](https://github.com/PrismLibrary), если интересует реально работающее приложение на PRISM, хоть и с не самым лучшим кодом, то вот мой [хобби-проект](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/), пример [регистрации модулей](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client/Bootstrapper.cs#L45), [регистрация сервисов](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.CoreModule/CoreModuleInit.cs)

Comment: СПАСИБО гляну обязательно

Comment: @Aldmi обновил ответ